# Error : "GraphQL error: Invalid Version: 1.17 " while deploying to prisma cloud

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, graphql, prisma

I am creating a server in prisma cloud using heruko and getting a vague error
[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O53zq.png)

Is anyone getting the same error?

Comment: Database is easily created but creating a server fails using prisma cloud

Comment: I'm getting the same error as you, I reached out to their support and they replied that they are aware of this issue and working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. Recreate Prisma server again.